Closing div at start of twig template is removed at render
Issue Overview:
I have a entity embed container that is added in ckeditor. Theres a custom template suggestion that renders the template.
For styling reasons, I need to close out the wrapping div around ckeditor, render the entity embed container template html, then reopen the wrapping div for ckeditor.
In other words, my template needs to look like:
</div>
<div {{ attributes }}>
  <div class="some-class">
    {{ children }}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wysiwyg-styles">

However, when this template is rendered, the opening closing </div> and the closing <div class="wysiwyg-styles"> html is removed.
Question:
Is there a way to force this html to be rendered in twig? Does something else need to be configured (render array, etc)?
If anything needs clarification, let me know!

This may be a bug/feature request for the module you’re using. Seems like it runs the template through an HTML corrector before it’s added to the full document in the WYSIWYG, which doesn’t seem optimal. On the flip side, they may just say that only fully valid, self-contained, markup is supported, for security or other reasons.

Have you investigated how the outer container is rendered? You might be better able to do what you want at that level. If there's not a way to target this instance specifically, consider if you can add suggestions based on the context.

A CSS style like "display: contents;" often is an easier alternative to rewriting the HTML structure.
